# Remove certain pattern of characters on a file name in Python

Tags: python

I need to grab the name of a directory and see if it matches a certain pattern inwithin the name string, on this case [FLAC] and remove such pattern with its preceding spaces. I will then keep that on a variable and rename the directory itself. How can I do this in Python ?

This is the code I am trying right now :

```
def cfn(dpath):
    for df in os.listdir(dpath):
        if df.endswith('[FLAC]'):
           df.strip('[FLAC]')
           print(df)
```

Comment: *"How can I do this in Python ?"* - You can do it by writing code. Try it, and then [edit] your question to show us what you've written and what your *specific* question is.

Comment: You should try to come up with some example code, or even pseudo-code. It will be much easier for people to understand your question and help you.

Comment: `strip` doesn't do what you think. It's going to strip all the characters in that string, as many times as they occur, from both ends of the string. So `ACDC`.strip('[FLAC]')` returns `'D'` because it removed the run of `AC` at the front and `C` and the end. Of course, none of that matters, because you never assign the result (`str` is immutable; all methods return new `str` leaving original `str` unchanged). You probably want something like `if df.endswith('[FLAC]'):` `df = df[:-len('[FLAC]')]`, `print(df)`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are asking how to rename a directory programmatically I'm going to assume you have a lot of them to do. (recursively?)
you will need:

Here is the structure of the program.

```
import os
my_list = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('./'):
    #append the root to a list to my_list if it meets the criteria
for dir in my_list:
     #change the name of the dir here.
```

Comment: What I want to do is to recursively strip certain patterns on a directory name and store that on a variable so I can append the resulting directory name to a file, renaming it. But Initially what I wanted to know is how to strip / remove unwanted parts of the directory name that match certain patters, like on the example [FLAC], or [EAC], etc.

Comment: string manipulation on the directoryName using the "re" module or split() and then shutil.move(src, dat) to rename the directory.